# Creating an index bar chart in Highcharter

Tags: r, r-highcharter

I'm trying to create a bar chart showing Cost of Living indexed to the U.S. value (100) in the Highcharter package in R. So I want the bars the start at 100 and either extend to the right or the left of 100. I have the basic bar chart down, but I can't figure out how to move the center line of the chart to 100. I'm trying to get it to look something like this: http://drawingwithnumbers.artisart.org/moving-the-center-line-of-a-bar-chart-with-a-gantt-chart/

Here's the data I'm working with:

```
States <- c('Tennessee','Michigan','Indiana','Ohio','Kentucky','West Virginia','North Carolina','Virginia','Pennsylvania','Delaware','New Jersey','Maryland','New York')
Cost_of_Living <- c(88.7,88.9,90,90.8,90.9,91.1,94.9,100.7,101.7,108.1,125.1,129.7,139.1)
costliving <- data.frame(States, Cost_of_Living)
```

And here's the code I have for the bar chart, just the basic bar chart

```
costliving_graph <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Cost of Living by State (2020)") %>%
  hc_add_series (costliving, "bar", hcaes(x = States, y = Cost_of_Living)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = costliving$States) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Indexed to the U.S. (U.S. Value = 100)"))%>%
  hc_plotOptions (bar = list(colorByPoint = TRUE)) %>%
  hc_legend (enabled = FALSE)%>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "MSA Regional Price Parities: {point.y}", headerFormat ="")
costliving_graph
```

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking examples on highcharter website I changed the charttype to `columnrange` and added new vars `low` and `high` to the dataframe. Try this:

```
library(highcharter)
library(dplyr)

States <- c('Tennessee','Michigan','Indiana','Ohio','Kentucky','West Virginia','North Carolina','Virginia','Pennsylvania','Delaware','New Jersey','Maryland','New York')
Cost_of_Living <- c(88.7,88.9,90,90.8,90.9,91.1,94.9,100.7,101.7,108.1,125.1,129.7,139.1)
costliving <- data.frame(States, Cost_of_Living) %>% 
  mutate(low = pmin(Cost_of_Living, 100),
         high = pmax(Cost_of_Living, 100))

costliving_graph <- highchart() %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Cost of Living by State (2020)") %>%
  hc_add_series(costliving, "columnrange", hcaes(x = States, y = Cost_of_Living, low = low, high = high)) %>%
  hc_xAxis(categories = costliving$States) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Indexed to the U.S. (U.S. Value = 100)"))%>%
  hc_plotOptions (bar = list(colorByPoint = TRUE)) %>%
  hc_legend (enabled = FALSE)%>%
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "MSA Regional Price Parities: {point.y}", headerFormat ="")
costliving_graph
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks! I edited the hc_tooltip portion to be `hc_tooltip(pointFormat = "MSA Regional Price Parities: {point.Cost_of_Living}", headerFormat ="")` so that the tooltip shows the index that way. Thanks again!